# uninitialized constant Prawn::FLOAT_PRECISION error showing while using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I took the approach of Railscast episode 153 revised.
My controller is

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController  

  def index    
    @examples = Example.all  
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html  
      format.csv { send_data @examples.to_csv }  
      format.xls { send_data @examples.to_csv }  
      format.pdf do  
        pdf = DownloadPdf.new(@examples)  
        send_data pdf.render, filename: 'generate_table.pdf',   
            type: 'application/pdf', disposition: "inline"  
      end  
    end  
  end  
end
```

and my download_pdf.rb file is

```
class DownloadPdf < Prawn::Document#make_table  

    require 'prawn/table'  
    def initialize(example)  
    super()  
        @examples = example  
        line_items  
    end

    def line_items  

    image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.png"      
    table [[1,2],[3,4]]  
  end  
end
```

I am using gems

> ```
> gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git", :ref => '8028ca0cd2'  
> gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0'
> ```

Thanx in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Update `prawn` gem by adding this to your Gemfile: `gem 'prawn'` and running `bundle install`.

**Longer answer**: You are using an old version of Prawn - that `ref` you are using in your `Gemfile` refers to somewhere in 2013. `prawn-table 0.1` is newer and requires a newer version of `prawn`. More precisely, it's using `Prawn`'s `::FLOAT_PRECISION` constant, which was added in [this 2014's commit](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/commit/48975a7e988879e4576cbc44c998fa6b4938f43d) to `Prawn`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below on Gemfile

```
gem 'prawn'
```

and then remove `Gemfile.lock`

and then

`bundle install`

restart server

Comment: How does this add to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `round(2)`  like this..

```
val= 456.7890999999
val.round(2)
```

and Ans will be **456.79**